# setting tab index for children in knockout binding

Tags: knockout.js, parent, tabindex

I have a table data bound using knockout. Here, I have parent-child like rows. e.g.

```
 <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <select data-bind="value:Required, enable:RequiredActive, attr:{tabindex: 43 * ($index() + 1) }">
                                        <option value="E">Eligible</option>
                                        <option value="O">On</option>
                                        <option value="F">Off</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                   <input data-bind="value:SetupTime, attr: { title: tabindex: 44 * ($index() + 1) }"/>
                                   <input data-bind="value:CloseTime, attr: { title: tabindex: 45 * ($index() + 1) }" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: WorkSegments">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <select data-bind="options:Locations, value:Location, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'ID', attr:{tabindex: 49 * ($parentContext.$index + 1) }" >
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: WorkSegments">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <select class="combobox" data-bind="options:EmployeeRoles, value:Role, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'ID', attr:{tabindex: 49 * ($parentContext.$index + 1)}" >
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
```

Here, the Location and EmployeeRole drop downs are children and can occur multiple times within the parent. Therefore when setting the tab index I've used '$parentContext.$index', but at runtime, for all the child controls I get tabindex='NAN'

I've also tried with $parent.index(), but no luck.

Appreciate some help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `$parentContext.$index()` not a `$parent.index()`:

```
<select data-bind="options:Locations, value:Location, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'ID', attr:{tabindex: 49 * ($parentContext.$index() + 1) }" >
                                                    </select>
```

Here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/CVL4q/

Comment: thnks, that worked! My mistake was I was using $parentContext.$index instead of $parentContext.$index()